# Как написать скрипт для блокировки клавиатуры?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

Как написать скрипт для блокировки клавиатуры на python ? ( OS - Ubuntu ) 
Какие есть пакеты для этого ?

Answer (score 2):

Есть утилита, xtrlock, она блокирует клавиатуру пока не будет введён пароль. Кроме этого ещё мышь блокируется.
из bashа устанавливаем утилиту

```
sudo apt-get install xtrlock
```

Из самого Pythonа

```
import os
os.system("xtrlock") # запускаем утилиту с нужными ключами
```

По [ссылке](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=993800) более подробно и ссылочка на [гитхаб](https://github.com/jarun/xtrlock)

Comment: Почему бы не пользоваться традиционным `xlock` или через `xscreensaver`?

Comment: @0andriy просто первое что в голову пришлом : )